# Forking in Linux and the use of setsid()

Tags: c, linux, fork

I have a sample code and I'm at loss in understanding how to figure out what's happening.
I'm only showing relevant parts.  The problem is `make_daemon()`.

From what I understand about forking is that code from `close(0)` onwards is executed by the child which should have a `pid == 0`.

What happens when the code hits `return -1`?  Does the code return to the parent or does it exit? Does the child p process code execute if(share) in Monitor()?

This code is an extract from Monitor.c in mdadm.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
int Monitor( struct mddev_dev *devlist,
    char *mailaddr, char *alert_cmd,
    struct context *c,
    int daemonise, int oneshot,
    int dosyslog, char *pidfile, int increments,
    int share )
{
    if (daemonise) {
        int rv = make_daemon(pidfile);
        if (rv >= 0)
            return rv;
    }
    if (share)
        if (check_one_sharer(c->scan))
            return 1;
    /* etc .... */
}

static int make_daemon(char *pidfile)
{
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) {
        if (!pidfile)
            printf("%d\n", pid);
        else {
            FILE *pid_file;
            pid_file=fopen(pidfile, "w");
            if (!pid_file)
                perror("cannot create pid file");
            else {
                fprintf(pid_file,"%d\n", pid);
                fclose(pid_file);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("daemonise");
        return 1;
    }
    close(0);
    open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
    dup2(0,1);
    dup2(0,2);
    setsid();
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This code is slightly incorrect -- after a `fork()`, only one process should terminate normally (using `exit` or returning), the other should use `_exit`.

Comment: From what I've been reading recently I thought that only the child process should do an _exit() and the parent either returns or uses exit().  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That depends on which of them continues with the same image. In this question, the child process goes on and the parent process exits, so the roles are reversed. If the child goes on to call `execve()`, this is equivalent to `_exit()`, as the process image is destroyed without running the C library cleanup, destructors and `atexit()` callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

`fork` can return three types of return values:

- a positive number: this only happens in the parent: it is the pid of a successfully created child.
- zero: this is only returned in the child and indicates that this code now executes in the child. This is **not** the pid of the child, use `getpid` to obtain the pid of the child.
- a negative value (commonly `-1`). This is also only ever returned in the parent and indicates that `fork` failed for whatever reason and no child was created.

As to what your code does: yes the child will continue at `close(0);` provided that a child was indeed created.

When your cild hits `return -1` it will return to whatever function called `make_daemon` back in the parent and will continue execution at that point. Normally forked children would do whatever they are supposed to do and then call `exit` in order not to mess up what the parent was doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but here's where I'm confused.  If a process calls fork() and does not use wait() for the child to finish and the child returns normally without doing exit() will the child process be ended when it returns to its parent or will it carry on executing the same code as the process that forked it.

Comment: The child never returns to the parent.  They are 2 separate processes.    Regardless of how the child ends - exit, return, crash, whatever - it is dead.  The only thing left behind is an entry in the system process table (i.e. a zombie) that will remain there until either the parent collects it via `wait` or the parent itself dies, in which case it will be inherited by init and disposed of.

Comment: Thanks Duck for your explanation.  Could you then please tell me what happens in make_daemon() when the child process hits return -1.  Does it return to the function that called it or is the child process terminated?  This is the bit that's confusing me.  The comment from Sergey suggests that the child process returns back to caller.

Comment: @Smithy The child process returns to a copy of the calling function (in the same state it was left in the parent) **in the child**. When you `fork()` you create an exact copy of the parent process except for the return value of `fork()` itself. The child will continue to run a copy of the parent process until it exits normally (by calling `exit` or returning from `main`) or abnormally.